# Reading Bluetooth data and command (Raspberry pi 3)

Tags: bluetooth, controller, raspberry-pi3

I am currently working on a project that make me control media center and a few domotic parts in my living room.

I have connected on my raspberry pi 3 a NAS, my Spotify account (with hifiberry, controls to close my amp, my PC and a few lights...

At first to control it all I programmed a web server that I can access on my phone. That made the job but it is not completely user friendly since I have to have my phone go to the interface and do whatever I have to... And I'm not a web designer  it's far from perfect!

I've made some research and I have decided to build a bluetooth remote control (raspberry pi 3 do have Bluetooth low energy).
Since nothing exist as I want, it is going to be a custom one made with Arduino mini and hm10 module.

But I'm stuck on the raspberry part!

**How can I read the Bluetooth data send by my remote and launch scripts according to the command sent?**

Via a serial listener of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact, you should use a serial port to connect your pi with Bluetooth module.
You then use software input information for your purposes, but you must first implement the hardware and hardware interface first.
You can build application software with the Python programming language.